# Is there a way to eliminate the repetition in this linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

This is a query to return search results, but I feel it could be cleaned up a little.  I just don't know how.

```
var queryResult = (from r in dc.Retailers
                    where
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) ||
                        SqlFunctions.PatIndex(firstName.Trim(), r.FirstName.Trim()) > 0) &&
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) ||
                        SqlFunctions.PatIndex(lastName.Trim(), r.LastName.Trim()) > 0) &&
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyName) ||
                        SqlFunctions.PatIndex(companyName.Trim(), r.CompanyName.Trim()) > 0) &&
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(phone) ||
                        SqlFunctions.PatIndex(phone.Trim(), r.Phone.Trim()) > 0) &&
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) ||
                        SqlFunctions.PatIndex(email.Trim(), r.Email.Trim()) > 0) &&
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(city) ||
                        SqlFunctions.PatIndex(city.Trim(), r.City.Trim()) > 0) &&
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip) ||
                        SqlFunctions.PatIndex(zip.Trim(), r.Zip.Trim()) > 0) &&
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(state) ||
                        SqlFunctions.PatIndex(state.Trim(), r.State.Trim()) > 0) &&
                        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) ||
                        SqlFunctions.PatIndex(country.Trim(), r.Country.Trim()) > 0)
                    select r
    );
```

Update: For those confused by the query.  Here is another version, which is probably better because it only builds the where parts when necessary.  But I would still like to reduce the repetition.

```
var queryResult = (from r in dc.Retailers select r);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(firstName.Trim(), ex.FirstName.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(lastName.Trim(), ex.LastName.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(companyName))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(companyName.Trim(), ex.CompanyName.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phone))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(phone.Trim(), ex.Phone.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(email.Trim(), ex.Email.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(city.Trim(), ex.City.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(zip))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(zip.Trim(), ex.Zip.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(country))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(country.Trim(), ex.Country.Trim()) > 0);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state))
    queryResult = queryResult.Where(ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(state.Trim(), ex.State.Trim()) > 0);
```

Comment: What is the point of the query? It looks like, for each field, you're searching for Retailers where the field is null or empty OR is not null or empty... which doesn't make sense.

Comment: It only filters by a search criteria if a value exists.  For example.  If you type in a state, it will only filter by state.  If you type in a state and a zip, it will filter by both.

Comment: I think I'd exploit the fact that `IQueryable<T>` can be "built" from multiple chained calls, ie make a function that takes and returns an `IQueryable` for each search criteria.

Comment: You want to be careful while trying to refactor this code. You may end up writing code which does filtering on the client side instead of doing it in the database. Because you have all these local variables, it will be hard to make it more generic. Look in to PredicateBuilder -http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx class to help you build this more dynamically if you were to get rid of the local variables.

Answer (score 3):

Apply the common refactoring used for repeated code: extracting a method. In your case, creating the method won't be trivial, because you want to create a different `Expression` each time. That is, unless you use [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx):

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereEqualsByPatIndex<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query, string value, Expression<Func<T, string>> propertyExpression)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        return query;

   return query.Where(
       ex => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(
           value.Trim(), propertyExpression.Invoke(ex, propertyExpression).Trim()) > 0);
}
```

Usage would be like this (that call to `AsExpandable()` is important):

```
dc.Retailers
  .AsExpandable()
  .WhereEqualsByPatIndex(firstName, ex => ex.FirstName)
  .WhereEqualsByPatIndex(lastName, ex => ex.LastName)
```

Comment: Great answer. I did not know about AsExpandable.

Comment: @SolutionYogi Regarding [your suggested edit](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13870): without the call to `AsExpandable()`, the code would throw an exception, saying that EF doesn't understand the expression. There are some cases where doing things incorrectly results in performing the filtering on the client, but this is not one of them.